# Vuetify + Nuxt: Recursive Table Of Contents issues?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to create a Table Of Contents (TOC) component, using Vuetify and Nuxt. Locally I am using a new nuxt app (with vuetify selected) from

```
npx create-nuxt-app my-app
```

and here is the [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tableofcontents-n0gdh). You will need to go full screen to view the TOC as it is a `navigation-drawer` bound to the right of the screen.

Locally, it renders as:

[image]

On [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tableofcontents-n0gdh) it rends as:
[image]

I have double checked the versions and `nuxt.config.js` file. They are the same.

So what is the desired result?
I like the auto indentation of my local version. Unfortunately, elements without children (e.g. `h2-1`), do not get indented even though it is at the same level as `h2-2`.

I would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Result of your codesandbox is empty.

Comment: @ManUtopiK as stated in OP it is right nav bar, so you need to have a wide enough screen to see it. You will have to open the full display (i.e. https://n0gdh.sse.codesandbox.io/)

Comment: I got 34" screen, but not opened in full screen. I got it now!

Comment: But if it's working locally, why you want to have the same in code sandbox? I don't understand the purpose of your question...

Comment: Yes, I agree that there is a misunderstanding between us. In the images in the post, you see there are two different outputs despite the same code. The indents on the local version are nice, but not completely correct. notice h2-1 should be indented @ManUtopiK

Answer (score 0):

You can add indentation for each subgroup by adding that in your css:

```css
.v-list-item-group > div {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```